# Have maps been removed from the 'Demolition' playlist?

Tags: call-of-duty-black-ops

I began playing Black Ops again after some time, I've since prestiged and levelled to 48. All this time I've been playing demolition and I've noticed a few of the default maps are no longer playable?

- Jungle
- Firing Range
- Havana
- Nuke Town (Used to be rare)

Have these maps been removed and if so, why?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to [this forum](http://www.codvs.com/exactly-what-maps-have-been-removed-from-demolition-t316408.html):

> Those four maps have been removed because of spawn killing, not spawn trapping. There's a big difference. Spawn killing is literally killing people the second they spawn giving them no chance to move or even fight back. Spawn trapping still gives the team a chance to fight out of their spawn.
>
> Those 4 maps had the most obvious spawns in Demo, thats why they were removed.

Comment: That's such a shame. It's just as easy to spawn kill on most of the other maps. I can understand why they would remove Nuke Town and Firing Range.